# How to make <img style> clickable

Tags: html, css, tags

I am using the following code:

```
<img style="border:2px solid #3591c0;
width:200;
height:200;
border-radius-30px;
-moz-border-radius:30px;
-khtml-border-radius:30px;
-webkit-border-radius:30px;"
src="1.jpg"/></style>
```

How can I make the image in this code clickable?

Comment: Believe you might are mixing up the *attribute* `style` with the *tag* (element) `style`. `<img style=...` does not open a new `<style>` tag. `<img>` is one `<style>` another. Anyway we see it. You can not have HTML inside the `<style>` tag – as such the `</style>` is bad.

Comment: I tried it with this code below and it doesn't seem to work with a div tag? is there something else I can use?<div style="border: 2px solid #ffc244;
            border-radius: 30px;
            -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
            width: 990px;
            height: 240px;
            background: url('2.JPG');" />

Comment: You can not use self-closing syntax `/>` on div. Use [this](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML and [this](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to validate your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in an anchor `<a>` tag, which would make it a link.

```
<a>
    <img style="border:2px solid #3591c0;
    width:200;
    height:200;
    border-radius-30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -khtml-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;"
    src="1.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround it in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="destination.html">
    <img style="border:2px solid #3591c0;
    width:200;
    height:200;
    border-radius-30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -khtml-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;"
    src="1.jpg"/>
</a>
```

where "destination.html" is the file path or link where you want the user to be redirected to. And yes, you don't need the `</style>` tag.

This is all shown in the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6Dq/5/

Comment: *Don't need the `</style>`* is to weak. It is bad markup as we can't have HTML inside `<style>`.

Comment: Could you select this as "best answer" if it answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that `<img>` tage within an `<a>` tag. In addition, `</style>` is not needed.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
  <img style="border:2px solid #3591c0;
  width:200;
  height:200;
  border-radius-30px;
  -moz-border-radius:30px;
  -khtml-border-radius:30px;
  -webkit-border-radius:30px;"
  src="1.jpg"/>
</a>
```